# Parsing ill formatted json column in redshift sql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, amazon-redshift

I want to query a json array column (data format super) from a redshift table. The problem is the values contain a lot of back slashes which is causing errors during parsing (see below for example). Could someone please suggest some solution which might have worked for you? I want to extract all values from array (in the example below all names, status, etc.)
Example value -

> "[{"name":"check_missing_inputs","status":"EXECUTED","parameters":{"inputs_dict":"{\"date_of_birth\":
> \"1900-01-01\"}"},"result":"{\"any_missing_input\": false,
> \"return_message\": \"all good\"}","execution_time":0},
> {"name":"age","status":"EXECUTED","parameters":{"date_of_birth":"1900-01-01"},"result":"53","execution_time":0}]"

Thanks!

Comment: Replacing the backslashes to make it valid json?

Comment: @NickW in the results key there might be legit value which would have \ which I don't want to replace. So it is a bit tricky that way.

Comment: So is \” a possible valid character combination? If it is, how are you planning to identify where it’s valid and where it’s not? If it isn’t then just replace \” with “

Comment: Can you write a python UDF to un-escape the JSON and then proceed after using that with json_parse?

Comment: Have your tried using [JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) ?

Comment: I tried replacing the \ and then json_extract_path_text and json_extract_array_element_text but no success